# Issue in connecting to docker mongo container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect the mongo container but in the node js application, I am getting errors on starting the server.

```
node server.js
app listening on port 3000!
/home/aniket/node_applications/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:698
          throw error;
          ^

MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/aniket/node_applications/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      'mongodb:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'mongodb:27017',
        error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
            at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
          name: 'MongoNetworkError'
        },
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 2835489,
        lastWriteDate: null,
        opTime: null,
        type: 'Unknown',
        topologyVersion: undefined,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: []
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let fs = require('fs');
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
  });

app.get('/profile-picture', function (req, res) {
  let img = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "images/profile-1.jpg"));
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
  res.end(img, 'binary');
});


// use when starting application as docker container
let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017";

// pass these options to mongo client connect request to avoid DeprecationWarning for current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine
let mongoClientOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

// "user-account" in demo with docker. "my-db" in demo with docker-compose
let databaseName = "my-db";

app.post('/update-profile', function (req, res) {
  let userObj = req.body;

  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlDocker, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);
    userObj['userid'] = 1;

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };
    let newvalues = { $set: userObj };

    db.collection("users").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, {upsert: true}, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      client.close();
    });

  });
  // Send response
  res.send(userObj);
});

app.get('/get-profile', function (req, res) {
  let response = {};
  // Connect to the db
  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlDocker, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };

    db.collection("users").findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      response = result;
      client.close();

      // Send response
      res.send(response ? response : {});
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I tried all the below things but the error is same

let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017";

let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb";

let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb://mongo:27017";

Comment: try changing name to  mongodb://admin:password@`hostname-of-machine`:27017

Comment: @fly2matrix After getting hostname and doing this works let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@Linuxbeta:27017"; My question is then how it will connect to docker container?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your application is not on the docker and `monogodb` hostname can be resolved by any docker-container which is also installed on the same docker-daemon.

Otherwise you have to use hostname of docker-daemon and port exposed/bind on host-machine.

Another way is to add nodejs container in your docker-compose.yml and mount source code directory to node.js  container and run your application within nodejs container.

Take reference from : https://medium.com/zenofai/how-to-build-a-node-js-and-mongodb-application-with-docker-containers-15e535baabf5

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [“node”, “app.js”]
```

Comment: @flymatrix WHy I need to create a docker image ?? I just want to make use of docker-compose

Comment: You can mount source directory to /app directory in a container having node.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by passing the credentials as options when connecting with mongodb. Change it:

```
let mongoClientOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };
```

For this:

```
let mongoClientOptions = { authSource: "admin", user: "admin", pass: "password", useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };
```

After that you can use the URI without adding the credentials it should work, in your case something like this:

```
let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://mongodb:27017";
```

let me know if it worked for you..

Comment: have you tried this solution by changing the `mongodb` hostname to`<hostname-of-machine>`, as suggested by @AniketShivamTiwari above?